# How to set object instance in initializer and immediately access property?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working against a particular SDK in the .NET Framework (`CRM SDK`, however not critical to this question; just background) that allows me to write an expression against a data repository and return me results. The *key* here is that the query *actually* executed relies on *which* fields I ask for when the query is executed.

So if I run an expression that has 6000 items it might take 5 minutes to return *all* 120 columns and all *6000* records. However, if I only ask for 5-6 fields/columns, it might only take 5-10 seconds to return all 6000 items. The critical key here is which fields I ask for all in the object initializer affects the query run by the SDK.

To this end, I'm having trouble accessing a property of type `EntityReference` in my `object initializer` and immediately access a property on it in 1 call. Some code to explain - the problematic code below. It's also *Very fast* because query executed only asks for 3 properties, so data returned is small:

```
var results = allAccountsQuery.Select(account => new Account
{
  AccountNo = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("AccountNumber"),
  //AccountID NOT working!
  AccountID = new EntityReference() { Id = account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("AccountID").Id }.Id,
  Name = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("AccountName")
}).ToList();
```

The offending line is as follows:

```
AccountID = new EntityReference() { Id = account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("AccountID").Id }.Id
```

As you can see, I'm *trying* to instantiate an instance of `EntityReference`, initialize it, and then immediately access it's property on the back end. It fails with `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

The following code works, but is super inefficient, because it brings back *everything*. The SDK is preforming some under the covers magic to only evaluate the query based on the fields asked for in an `object initiazlizer`. In this case the query is being evaluating and in the 1st iteration of the loop it brings back *everything*, but it works:

```
List<Account> allAccounts = new List<Account>();
//Super slow - framework actually gets back ALL accounts in 1st iteration
foreach (var account in allAccountsQuery)
{
  Account newAccount = new Account
  {
     AccountNo = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("AccountNumber"),
     Name = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("AccountName")
  };

  //WORKS: This separate instantiation and then accessing of the property works!!
  //Note it is done in 2 steps outside the object initializer
  //Need to see if I can do this in an object initializer instead of separately
  EntityReference ef = account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("AccountID");
  newAccount.AccountID = ef.Id;

  allAccounts.Add(newAccount);
}
```

So the question is how can I dictate an `EntityReference` instance and extract it's property `Id` in an object initializer so that my resulting evaluating query is small?

Comment: What throws the nullref though? It could be the whole initializer.. or simply this part: `account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("AccountID").Id`. Check that first.

Comment: It's that line, because if I remove it from being defined the code works and the `results` collection is populated. That's the offending property.

Comment: if you get `NullReference` on that line, you should get an exception in `foreach` loop as well,do you ?

Comment: Then you need to figure out why `GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("AccountID")` is returning `null` for a specific account. The issue seems to be there.. and not with the initializer.

Comment: I believe the syntax I have in the expression `object initializer` _is not_ equivalent to the code outside the `Account` `object initializer` in the `foreach` loop. The `foreach` creates an instantiation on 1 line and accesses the property in another. Even ReSharper didn't find a way to include that in the `object initializer` and left it outside. Can it be done?

Comment: What is the stack trace on the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus far the best **working** solution I have found is to load the initial data into an anonymous type collection, and then load the actual concrete type collection based on it:

```
//Anonymous type collection
var accounts = allAccountsQuery.Select(account => new
{
  AccountNo = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("AccountNumber"),
  AccountID = account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("AccountID"),
  Name = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("AccountName")
}).ToList();
```

Now that I did the dirty work to get the `EntityReference` instance defined, I can access it's `.Id` property when populating the concrete type:

```
var results = accounts.Select(account => new Account
{
  AccountNo = account.AccountNo,
  AccountID = account.AccountID.Id,
  Name = account.Name
}).ToList();
```

This is tested and working. the `results` collection has the realized `.Id` property defined. However as you see I still had to do it in 2 steps. It does however solve my problem because the query runs quickly. I'm still open to being able to do this in 1 object initializer because this solution can get lengthy if I have to create a sort of *temporary* holding tank just to then access and map it's property later.

I'd still prefer an answer that does this loading in a single object initializer.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly you want to achieve a request comparable to the following SQL statement

```
SELECT AccountNumber, Id, Name FROM Accounts
```

A comparable request with the CRM SDK would be

```
AccountSet.Select(account => new Account
{
  AccountNumber = account.AccountNumber,
  Id = account.Id,
  Name = account.Name
})
```

***Hint:*** The Id or AccountId is only a `Guid`. It is *not* an `EntityReference`.

Therefore your call to `account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("AccountID")` will return `null`. Therefore you get a `NullReference` when accesing the `Id` Property.

This results in the following QueryExpression

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<QueryExpression xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ColumnSet>
    <AllColumns>false</AllColumns>
    <Columns xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <d3p1:string>accountnumber</d3p1:string>
      <d3p1:string>name</d3p1:string>
    </Columns>
  </ColumnSet>
  <Criteria>
    <Conditions />
    <FilterOperator>And</FilterOperator>
    <Filters />
  </Criteria>
  <Distinct>false</Distinct>
  <EntityName>account</EntityName>
  <LinkEntities />
  <Orders />
  <PageInfo>
    <Count>0</Count>
    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
    <PagingCookie i:nil="true" />
    <ReturnTotalRecordCount>false</ReturnTotalRecordCount>
  </PageInfo>
  <NoLock>false</NoLock>
</QueryExpression>
```

So only these three attributes are requested and included in the result

Comment: The comment you made "The Id or AccountId is only a Guid. It is not an EntityReference" is not true. If I write out to a text file, or inspect directly during debugging, I can see the field I'm using is of type `EntityReference`. Have a look: `key: 'AccountID' value: 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference'` What you have shown I already knew to be true for all simple types (string, int, etc.) but inevitably, I will need (including here) an `EntityReference` attribute and I still haven't found a way to cast and access one of it's properties in a single object initializer.

Comment: @atconway just to make sure: you're talking about the standard Account entity and you mean for sure the AccountId property?

Comment: No you are correct there. As typical with SO posts, I have 'obfuscated' some of the field names. Bottom line - the property I'm accessing is of type `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference`. This is really a `C#` question and not a `CRM` how to. It's a general question about how to access an instance property's field directly in an object initializer (same really goes for _any_ .NET instance object). I can do it in (2) steps, just not in 1.

Comment: I will say the view you provided of the `QueryExpression` in `XML` was nice to validate what actually is being sent across the line. How did you produce that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your solution but I'm pretty sure that you really want to be limiting your columns on the query expression and then using the .ToEntity<> method to cast your collection to Accounts.

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("account");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "AccountId", "AccountNumber", "AccountName" });
List<Account> allAccounts = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.Select(account => account.ToEntity<Account>()).ToList<Account>();
```

Comment: I'm actually using a different approach than yours. Your solution uses early bound entities, and I'm using late bound (no VS2013 support for CRM 2011 SDK to create early bound entities, and not doing a hack solution). Also I'm using the LINQ/Expression syntax to limit columns via what my expression requires doing the same thing as your `ColumnSet` and `RetrieveMultiple` calls. There are several ways the `SDK` allows you to pull data. I think my OP is not being understood well. In fact I've posted a solution so still looking for 1 time object initializer approach.

Comment: My solution could be converted to a late binding model without making significant changes.  However on second look I agree that our code could be vastly different in the way that it queries CRM.  I assumed that the allAccountsQuery was a DataCollection or similar object, but from your comment it seems that it is something different entirely.  That use of LINQ is pretty interesting and something I haven't been exposed to before, is there some resource you would suggest that explains how you are querying?

Comment: Yes - take a look at the links and resources from the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328028.aspx It has a bunch of information on querying `CRM` via `LINQ` or `Lambdas`.